# I want to connect to derby server from another machine using Bluetooth direct connection

Tags: java, database, derby

please i need your help badly i am able to create java database application that is connected to derby now i want to connect to that database from another machine using IP instead of localhost, i use Bluetooth direct connection to access the other machine.
Can it be possible if i connect my two machine with Bluetooth or it can only be done with LAN or Internet. I am getting this error: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:The connection was refused because the database remote was not found.

Comment: Derby client/server connections are made using TCP/IP. I believe there are ways to use TCP/IP over Bluetooth, but this is a networking question, not a Derby question.

Comment: I have connected my two machines using Bluetooth which i can access one from the other no problem with that at all. I have built java database application with the following jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/remote which works fine but my problem is when i want to access my database from another machine using using jdbc:derby://My IP:1527/remote.